# Why does bootstrap have a navbar-nav markup typically use unordered lists for links?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

A Bootstrap `navbar` is typically setup like this:

```
 <nav class="navbar">
     <a href="#" class="navbar-brand>Studio58</a>
     <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">L1</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">L2</a></li>
     </ul>
 </nav>
```

Just curious why the additional unordered list markup, `navbar-nav` and `nav-item` classes are necessary / used?  Why not just do:

```
 <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand>Studio58</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link"></a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link"></a>
</nav>
```

Comment: The Navbar component can support brand text (or image), multiple navigations, forms, as well as additional text.  Placement for these various items, especially as it pertains to responsive design (collapsing) requires additional wrappers.

Comment: For this use case it seems like the default could just be a flex box column and then have a responsive modifier on the nav element that changes it to a row in the event that the screen size gets beyond a certain breakpoint?

Comment: Perhaps, but consider your use case against what Bootstrap uses for an example of the component.  Yours is excessively simplistic and in no way represents the typical component that Bootstrap's developers created their CSS to support.  This is like holding up a diagram of a bicycle and wondering why your car can't be more like it.

Comment: You have to admit that bicycles are a lot cleaner and easier to maintain :)

Comment: Looking at it a little more though - it looks like the requirement they have in mind is that the link items mobile first view should be a column by default (Next to the logo - instead of having logo on top in the column) and then that will only go horizontal once the navbar-nav hits a certain breakpoint.

Comment: And honestly... your format *works* it just loses certain styling (and of course, the ability to responsively collapse).  Consider: https://www.bootply.com/QTXfQ6vCcK

Comment: From [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#base-nav): *"the nav links behave the same as nav items would, but without the extra markup."*. It's acceptable to do the simpler markup, and both ways are shown in the docs. The only time you should use `nav-item` is for [fill and justified](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#fill-and-justify).

Comment: @ZimSystem The behavior you pointed out is for `.nav` but the OP is discussing `.navbar-nav` which behaves somewhat differently from the base component.  For one, it doesn't accept the fill & justify classes (at least, not in the same fashion)